# Backup compatibility from SQL Server Enterprise 2008 to SQL Server Standard 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

I got an old database that I need to transfer from SQL Server 2008 to 2014.
The problem that occurred was that restoring the database in 2014 threw an error saying that it's not compatible, due to some functions that are only available in Enterprise edition.

> Database "---name---" cannot be started in this edition of sql server,
>   because part or all of object '---table_name---'is enabled with data
>   compression or vardecimal storage format are only supported in SQL
>   Server Enterprise Edition.

Is there a way to backup the old database with some sort of compatibility mode?

Comment: You can to use the export options: Dump to SQL. Or alternative use the options to copy tables directly from database to database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features;
```

This will show you what features you have enabled that need to be disabled.

I would restore a backup to an enterprise instance, and then begin to work from there to disable enterprise features After the above query returns no results you should be fine.

Comment: Instead of a temporary Enterprise instance, this seems like something a local Developer instance would also be useful for. It's supposed to have all the Enterprise features, and the restrictions on usage shouldn't be a problem in this case.

Comment: You're absolutely right, either or will do. I was just assuming since he's coming from a Enterprise instance, that he could just restore right back to it and do the work there, but if that's not an option, developer will do the trick.

Comment: I was thinking that if the Enterprise instance is a production server with many other users, the server admin might have a problem with the OP using it like that. :) But if that's not a problem, for example if no one else is using the server anyway, then I agree with your suggestion.